# Windows 7 undo default assignment for shortcuts

Tags: windows

By mistake I assigned the Open With option to JAVAW.EXE always ofr an EXE shortcut.
now all the shortcuts as by default assigned to JAWAW.EXE.
Is their any to undo that?

Answer (score 0):

Here this contains the default assosciations forget where I got them from so I uploaded them to dropbox

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b3avive9xmpi577/All_Default_File_Extentions.zip?dl=0

just unzip then rightclick merge the one you want which is Default_LNK